# Duplicating values in text file

Tags: python

I am using a text file to store values for a tkinter combobox.  If the user enters a value not in the file, I want it added.  Everything works fine, but if the user selects an existing value, it also is added again to the list.  I believe it is because I am returning stripped values and comparing against values with '\n'.  Any help on how to correct this is greatly appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

regionList = open('regions1.txt','r')

root = Tk()
root.configure()
varRegions = StringVar(root, value='')

class MainWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """Create Window Layout"""
        Boxfont = ('Arial', 12, 'bold')
        self.blank = Label(self,text='').grid(row=2,column=0)
        self.label = Label(self, font=Boxfont, text="Regions").grid(row=3,column=1)
        self.regcombo = ttk.Combobox(self, font = Boxfont, width = 16, textvariable = varRegions)
        self.regcombo.bind("<Return>", self.regcombo_onEnter)
        self.regcombo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',self.regcombo_onEnter)
        self.regcombo['values'] = regionList.readlines()
        self.regcombo.grid(row=3, column=2,sticky = W)
        self.blank = Label(self,text='').grid(row=4,column=0)

    def regcombo_onEnter(self,event):
        varRegions.set(varRegions.get().lower().strip())
        mytext = varRegions.get().strip()
        vals = self.regcombo.cget('values')
        self.regcombo.select_range(0,END)
        print(mytext)
        if not vals:
            self.regcombo.configure(values = (mytext,))
        elif mytext not in vals:
            with open('regions1.txt','a') as f:
                f.write('\n'+ mytext)
                self.regcombo.configure(values = vals + (mytext,))
                f.close
        return 'break'

app = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Remove the `\n`s?

Comment: @ScottHunter - In the combobox, I am removing the \n so it doesn't display extra spaces.  However, when the value is selected, it is looking back at the text file and doesn't find the value, so it adds it again with \n.  I want these values added to the file as separate lines and removing the \n when writing back just makes one long string. If the user types in 'Region 4' and it isn't in the list, it should be added.  But if they select 'Region 1' from the list, it should not be added back.  How  do I strip the \n for the combobox, and lookup the value in the text file without the \n?

Comment: Can you create an [mcve] for us??

Comment: @wwii - I have edited the question with a complete example.  The regions1 file has the following rows - 'Region 1', 'Region 2', 'Region 3', 'Region 4' -
 all on separate lines.  Thanks for your help!